# how to handle multiple fragments onbackpressed

Tags: android, fragment

The Main Activity having bottom navigation and contains 5 fragments in it. Each fragments having multiple fragment inside. how to handle the onbackpressed in it.

Homepage.java

```
public class Homepage extends AppCompatActivity {
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        Fragment selectedFragment = null;
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.home:
                selectedFragment = Fragment_home.newInstance();
                break;
            case R.id.eventsfeed:
                selectedFragment = Fragment_eventsfeed.newInstance();
                break;
            case R.id.events:
                selectedFragment = Fragment_events.newInstance();
                break;
            case R.id.messages:
                selectedFragment = Fragment_messages.newInstance();
                break;
            case R.id.settings:
                selectedFragment = Fragment_settings.newInstance();
                break;
        }
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.content, selectedFragment);
        transaction.commit();
        return true;

    }

};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.homepage);

    Fragment fragmentnewview = new Fragment_home();
    FragmentManager frMan = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction frTr = frMan.beginTransaction();
    frTr.add(R.id.content,fragmentnewview);
    frTr.commit();

    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
    BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(navigation);

}}
```

Fragment_home.java

```
public class Fragment_home extends Fragment {

public static Fragment_home newInstance(){
        Fragment_home fragment=new Fragment_home();
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    CardView card=(CardView)view.findViewById(R.id.next_page_home_card);

    card.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Fragment fragmentnewview = new Event_details();
            FragmentManager frMan = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction frTr = frMan.beginTransaction();
            frTr.add(R.id.content,fragmentnewview);
            frTr.commit();
        }
    });


    return view;
}
```

}

Inside that Fragment_home.java i have a card view when it clicked it goes to next fragment Event_Details.java

Event_Details.java

```
public class Event_details extends Fragment {
Button add_comments;
ImageButton back;
public static Event_details newInstance(){
    Event_details fragment=new Event_details();
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_details, container, false);
    add_comments=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.add_comment);

    back=(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.back);

    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Fragment fragmentnewview = new Fragment_home();
            FragmentManager frMan = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction frTr = frMan.beginTransaction();
            frTr.add(R.id.content,fragmentnewview);
            frTr.commit();
        }
    });
    add_comments.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Fragment fragmentnewview = new Comments();
            FragmentManager frMan = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction frTr = frMan.beginTransaction();
            frTr.add(R.id.content,fragmentnewview);
            frTr.commit();
        }
    });


    return view;
}
```

}

i have a button in Event_Details.java when clicked that it calls another fragment Comments.java

Comments.java

```
public class Comments extends Fragment {
ImageButton back;
public static Comments newInstance(){
    Comments fragment=new Comments();
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_your_comments, container, false);
    back=(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.back);

    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Fragment fragmentnewview = new Event_details();
            FragmentManager frMan = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction frTr = frMan.beginTransaction();
            frTr.add(R.id.content,fragmentnewview);
            frTr.commit();
        }
    });


    return view;
}
```

}

back.setOnClickListener is the image button to go back but i can't implement in the hardware back button.

Comment: Try to put your code, what you tested, what you did... we are not magicians to know what are you doing to solve the problem

Comment: i updated the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `@Override` your activity `onBackPressed()` method !!!
There are many good information and answers about your question ! if you want to become good programmer you need good research skills!!! :))
Try to research and solve the problem yourself . Write some code, and after all of it if you still can't resolve your problem i'll give you code for copy and paste :)

Comment: Yeah.. thanks you.. but i implement the both addtobackstank and popbackstack too..

Comment: i resolved the problem i changed teh frTr.add() to frTr.replace and implmented teh backstack in the code.. problem solved

Answer (score 0):

When you load a fragment, use addToBackStack(null) on the FragmentTransaction. If you do that, the back button will reverse the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

`@Override onBackPressed()
 method as @L.Petrosyan told, 
inside`onBackPressed()`get the current position of your viewpager using`viewPager.getCurrentItem();
`it will return you an`int` value. use that value to manage your code.